# How to increase performance of sin and cos using neon instructions?

Tags: c, arm, neon

How to use arm_neon.h headerfile to increase the performance of a code using sin and cos functions.?
The board used is a Xilinx T1 accelerator card with ARM architecture armv8-a and cortex a53.
Language is c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arm_neon.h` contains SIMD intrinsics, which offer a C API to access/invoke individual low level instructions.

Thus, if you intend to speed up `sin/cos` with `arm_neon.h`, the method is to rewrite those trigonometric functions using vector arithmetic calculating 4 values at the same time.

Things you need to concern are:

- the code needs to be branchless
- you need to define how accurate you need to be
- you need to define the input range (no need to handle multiples of 2*pi ?)
- you need to define input unit (radians vs degrees vs fractions of 2^n)

All of this will determine what kind of approximation to use -- polynomial, linear piece-wise, rational polynomial and what steps or corner cases can be omitted.

Comment: With 4 values at the same time, I'm implicitly assuming `float`, not `double` as the input and output types.

Comment: If you can cope with limited accuracy and can control input wrapping, then lookup tables are also a pretty good solution.